# Refactor Drupal site while preserving content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-content-types

My dilemma: My small team has been pegged with the task of refactoring/redesigning a rather large Drupal site. The site is littered with unused modules and content types, CSS/JS/HTML/etc hacks, and has a myriad of strange work-arounds for external data imports. I am currently the sole backend developer for the team, and our Drupal expertise is beginner level. We cannot build a custom CMS because of the amount of content that the site has combined with the complexity of Drupal's DB structure, it would be impossible to export it reliably; as well, content is being constantly added and modified on a daily basis.

My question: Is there any best practices, tips, advice, or any suggestions that anyone can provide that might aide us in our attempt to refactor this site?

Specifically...

1. Detecting, disabling, uninstalling, and removing unused modules and QAing afterwards.
2. Updating modules and QAing (systematic approach?).
3. Detecting and deleting unused content types.
4. Detecting and removing unused PHP code (tpls mostly).
5. Detecting and removing unused CSS/JS.

Answer (score 0):

On modules back-end page you have dependencies shown for every module. Is some other module using it and what other modules current module uses. So, if you see that module is not used by any other module and that it's feature is not needed you can try disabling it first, check if everything works well and finally remove the module.

About content types - go to content, check is there some node of specific content type you doubt it's not needed. If there are nodes of that type try viewing them. It they are not styled well...might be that they are not used/needed.

Php - hmm...you can i.e. add some line of your code writing out some thing, or even saving some text to the file and then open page...see if you'll get some output or something saved into your file. You can even call `exit()` function and check will it break the site.

Similar with JS - alert something or write to console to see will it be called.

And most important thing - make a backup of all files and database first!